# Запрос SQL с "вытаскиванием" данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Пишу программу на Java с БД на PostgreSQL, нужно получить таблицу и заменить в ней данные из другой таблицы.

Картинка для примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужен сам запрос `SQL`

сейчас запрос такой:

```
SELECT * FROM public.\"Court\";
```

Comment: а ваши размышления в виде запроса или ином можно увидеть?

Comment: Согласен в автором предыдущего комментария, здесь не решают за вас ваши задачи "с нуля" без попыток решения. Почитайте про оператор JOIN.

Comment: Вы что понимаете под "заменить данные" ? Они в таблице на диске должны стать новыми или вы хотите вывести эти данные не меняя в самой БД. И "_вызвать_" таблицу невозможно - она же таблица, а не функция какая нибудь ...

Comment: вывести эти данные не меняя в самой БД

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать **JOIN**

```
SELECT T1.key, T2.name FROM table1 T1 
JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.name = T2.key;
```

Подробнее можете почитать в [документации](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/tutorial-join.html)

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так. К слову предыдущий ответ был тоже верный, но лично я предпочитаю делать так как ниже, потому что используя верхний способ, для изменения каждого параметра, будет выполнятся подзапрос, а тут можно получить сразу нужный набор данных одним подзапросом. Для данного примера (изменяется всего 1 поле) существенно не отличается.

```
CREATE TABLE #data1 (id int, name varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE #data2 (id int, name varchar(max))

INSERT INTO #data1
SELECT 1,'11'
union all
SELECT 2,'22'
union all
SELECT 3,'33'

INSERT INTO #data2
SELECT 1,'aa'
union all
SELECT 2,'bb'
union all
SELECT 3,'ww'

select 'Первичные данные', * from #data1
select 'Первичные данные', * from #data2

UPDATE #data1
SET #data1.name = z.name
FROM
    (SELECT z.id, z.name FROM #data2 z) z
WHERE z.id = #data1.id

select 'Данные после преобразования', * from #data1
select 'Данные после преобразования', * from #data2
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте соединение таблиц.

Если у вас столбцы `key` из первой таблицы и `key` из второй таблицы имеют одинаковый набор значений, то используйте внутреннее соединение `inner join` (или просто `join`):

```
select t1.key, t2.name
from table1 t1 join table2 t2
     on t1.key = t2.key
```

---

Если у вас столбец `key` из первой таблицы, например, имеет некоторые значения, которых нет в столбце `key` из второй таблицы, то используйте внешнее соединение `left join`:

```
select t1.key, t2.name
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
     on t1.key = t2.key
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/de17d/1/0).